# MySQL UDF only works in `WHERE` clause when wrapped in `IF`

Tags: mysql, where-clause, user-defined-functions

I have a function like:

```
create function foo(<args>)
returns varchar(40)
begin
return sha1(concat_ws('-', <args>));
end
```

When I use it in a where clause like this I get no results:

```
where fooCol = foo(<args>)
```

But this works perfectly:

```
where if(fooCol = foo(<args>), true, false)
```

I'm totally perplexed by this. It must be some behavior of functions that I'm unaware of, but I've been unable to figure out why this would be.

**UPDATED**

Here is a more thorough example. All columns used are `varchar(40)`.

```
delimiter $$

create function fn($fk varchar(40))
returns varchar(40)
begin
    return sha1(concat_ws('-',
        -- Real function takes more arguments but I was able
        -- to reproduce with a simplified version like this.
        coalesce($fk, 'None')
    ));
end

$$

select
    *
from
    foo
    left join bar on bar.id = foo.bar_id
where
    foo.fooKey = fn(bar.barKey)
    -- This will return rows!
    -- if(foo.fooKey = fn(bar.barKey), true, false);
```

**UPDATE 2**

The above ONLY fails if `barKey` is null. If I simply pass `null` instead of using the field as an argument, it works.

Comment: Using a [very simplistic example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRou8gzRfkCKfFTgKzifrC/0) on 5.7, these both work as expected.  We'd likely need more information to determine what is happening, sample tables + data, where you are defining the function and how it is being called, etc.

Comment: Yeah I will update. I was just testing with simpler examples and those did work, I'm trying to find the point at which this happens...

Answer (score 1):

My problem appears to be caused by this bug:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86922

Time to upgrade MySQL!